# htaccess redirect but exclude whole ipv6 prefix

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to redirect visitors from my old domain to a new domain using .htaccess, however I would like to be able to visit the old domain myself by excluding my ipv4 & ipv6 from the redirect. If I fill in my exact ipv6 it's working but as it's changing often I would like to exclude my whole ipv6 prefix from the redirect.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^12.345.678.901
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^1234:123:1234:1:1234:1234:1234:1234
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^1234:123:1234::/48
RewriteRule .* http://www.example.com [NC,R=301,L]
```

The first two RewriteConds are working, the third unfortunately is not :(

Note: replaced my ip with some fake numbers

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it by using a different approach

```
<Files *>
ErrorDocument 403 http://www.example.com
Order deny,allow
Deny from all
Allow from 12.345.678.901
Allow from 1234:123:1234::/48
</Files>
```

However I would still like to know why the first option is not working